# O que são "gringas"?

Tags: significado, português-europeu

Na [letra da música](https://mao-morta.org/venus-em-chamas) Velocidade Escaldante do grupo Mão Morta, há uns miúdos que... deixam "gringas" a marcar livros?

> Os putos vêm só para dar um fix
> Estendem-se pelo quarto a folhear comics
> Esquecem **gringas** a marcar os livros
> E morrem de volúpia num esgar feliz
> Alguém me faz um bico

- Que são estas gringas?

Será um calão específico da zona de Braga, de onde o grupo é?
Será um uso lírico, relacionado com as mulheres no contexto das tertúlias descritas?

---

Só conheço para esta palavra o significado depreciativo/calão para "estrangeiro", que é também [o único indicado pelo dicionário Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/gringa):

> gringo ( grin·go ) — nome masculino
> [Depreciativo] Designação dada a estrangeiros, em especial a norte-americanos.

"gringa", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2023, https://dicionario.priberam.org/gringa .